# How to update state of a component with value from reducer state in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have reducer that gives me `carReducer`, which I can use as props in EditCar Component:

My `carReducer` is:

```
export default function carReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_SINGLECAR':
            return {
                ...state,
                next: action.payload
            }
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

And in EditCar Component I have declared `carReducer` as:

```
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            carReducer: state.carReducer
        }
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditCar);
```

Now in the same component I want to update my intialState `cardata` with this `carReducer` before the component loads.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        cardata: {}
    }
}
```

I tried using `componentWillReceiveProps` but this gives me `undefined` in both `nextProps.carReducer` and `this.props.carReducer`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.carReducer != this.props.carReducer) {
        this.setState({ cardata: nextProps.carReducer });
    }
}
```

I am new in `react-redux` so any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your reducer, action and your store code please?

Comment: From docs: React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with initial props during mounting: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Why do not you just assign props.carReader to cardata in the constructor? Anyway what you are doing is not considered a good practice, you just have the redux state, why copy it in the component state?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `componentWillRecieveProps` in this case. Just replace `next` with `carReducer` in your reducer

Comment: this.props.carReducer's value is accessible in render portion. But got undefined inside componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: There is no need to use componentWillRecieveProps in this case. I have update my answer,please replace next with carReducer in your reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 - Try to use `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState = ({
    cardata: this.props.carReducer
  })
}
```

Method 2 - You can try to do it in the constructor itself

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    cardata: props.carReducer
  }
}
```

Comment: Got `cardata` `undefined` from method 1 and in second case `cardata` didn't get changed at all i.e. it came empty.

Comment: It takes a few milliseconds to get data from reducer, so it is undefined initially. But when data comes, it must rerender itself. Your original `willRecieveProps()` should work.